# Water Pump Will Not Pressurize Over 30 PSI

Tags: plumbing, water, pump

I’ve been having issues with the water pump at my house. When I turn it on using the breaker in the main breaker panel, it turns on and moves the pressure to 30 psi according to the pressure gauge, but the pump won’t turn off. It just keeps running and I'm forced to turn it off using the breaker feeding it. In the past, I recall it being at least close to 40 psi or more.

This is the troubleshooting I performed:

At one point, the pump was turned on, and the tank reached 30 psi and the pump kept running. The valve allowing water to go to the house was turned off, then the pump was turned off through the breaker. The pressure gauge still showed 30 psi. I was trying to determine if water was going back into the well. This may not even be a valid test to check that.

The 30/50 pressure switch’s setpoints were changed for the pump to turn off at 30 psi. The pump was able to turn off, but after using a small quantity of water (guessing 3 gallons) the pump turned on at approximately 3 psi, thus this configuration is not feasible.

The control box was opened and it was confirmed that the wires leading to the pump motor show 240 volts. There are three wires leading to the pump motor. There are two particular wires that if measured across show ~358 volts. There are also two capacitors in the control box. One is used for starting the motor and the other for running the motor. The one for starting the motor looks as if the bottom of the capacitor is corroded. The control box is located near the tank in the garage, so there could still be an issue between the control box and pump motor.

The breaker panel leading to the pump switch shows 240 across the 2 poles, and the pressure switch shows 240 volts as well.

After draining the tank by opening a nearby valve, the tank bladder showed ~29.5 psi. There were no signs of water coming out the bladder when a little air was let out the bladder.

Pump Specs: Franklin Electric Model 2823008110, 1.5 HP, 60 Hz, 3450 RPM

Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: The pump is likely worn out from what you are saying. It cannot build the pressure due to a bad seal or gunked up seal/pump mechanism.

Comment: If it's a jet pump there may be debris in the jet.

Comment: 2823008110 is the model number of a submersible control box, not the pump itself.

Comment: How old is the pump? I agree with noybman, it sounds like it is worn out. Pulling a submersible pump is not normally a DIY project. Sounds like you need a good well pump service technician.

Comment: In my last house where I lived for 20 years, I had a similar problem. When the well guy came to service the pump he pulled the pump out of the well and found that some of the impellers were full of mud (clay and stuff) from in the well. He was able to clean the impellers, reinstall the pump and piping and everything worked perfectly. This may be your problem also.

Comment: I suspect the pump is about 24 years old.

Comment: Water table could have fallen. If so lower the jet